# Xml data on modal popup in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, xml, twitter-bootstrap

I have multiple xml file and an xsl file. My need is when i select one xml file and click on view button, details of xml file will be displayed on a popup.

I have added code like below:
 //get hiddenField value to get file name

string strCCDXml = hdnXmlFile.Value;

```
        //if a file selected 
        if (strCCDXml != string.Empty && chkCCDA.Checked)
        {
            xmlClinicData.Visible = true;
            xmlClinicData.TransformSource = "CCDA.xsl";
        }
```

Controls:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnView" runat="server" Text="View" data-toggle="modal" href="#modalViewData" OnClick="btnView_Click" />
 <div id="modalViewData" class="modal hide fade fullWidth modalDiv" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">                  
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="errorMsgDiv">
                        <span id="spnErrorMsg" runat="server" class="validateTips error"></span>
                    </div>
                    <asp:Xml ID="xmlClinicData" runat="server" Visible="true"></asp:Xml>
                </div>               
            </div>
```

inside view button click. But my modal popup is blank.